# Where clause fails if using same date in a "greater than or equal to" and a "less than or equal to"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does this query not return any rows when `date1`, `date2`, and `dateField` are the same and there are rows where `dateField == date1` that should be returned?

Examples:

```
select * from tableName where dateField >= date1 and dateField <= date2
```

Comment: Is `dateField` ***just*** a date? Or is it a datetime field?

Comment: And if it's a datetime field, is the time different?

Comment: Yes, it is a `smalldatetime`.

Comment: Does DateField has a value for the time in it ? maybe convert(date, dateField) >= convert(date, date1) might help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the time part of the `smalldatetime` field `dateField` used to be all zeros, and now it's not. The solution was to just compare the date portion of `dateField`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE 
CONVERT(DATE, dateField) >= date1 AND CONVERT(DATE, dateField) <= date2
```